# How to convert string to uniqueidentifier in Django?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-orm, guid

I'm trying to insert a pre-generated GUID to SQL Server database from another SQL Server database via Django ORM, but keep getting Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. I've already changed my field in model to UUID field and started creating
UUID object from my UUID character string, but still I get this mistake. What can I do to effectively insert this data to database?

Part of model:

```
class KmList(models.Model):
    project_guid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
```

Insertion code:

```
    km_objects = [
        KmList(
            project_guid=uuid.UUID(entry.projuid),
            km_no=entry.projectname,
            old_id=None,
            kp_name=entry.kp_name,
            rev_name=entry.nameproject,
            chief_name=entry.projectownername,
            department=entry.department,
        ) for entry in data
    ]
    KmList.objects.bulk_create(km_objects)
```

Comment: Can Django ORM even use `uniqueidentifier` columns on SQL Server? The [UUIDField Model documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) suggests that it cannot, i.e.: _A field for storing universally unique identifiers. Uses Python’s UUID class. When used on PostgreSQL, this stores in a uuid datatype, otherwise in a char(32)._ The inference being that Django tries to store a uuid formatted like `'a211091a49744f079818c5162bb0355d'` instead of `'a211091a-4974-4f07-9818-c5162bb0355d'` as SQL Server expects.

Comment: So maybe there is some way around it, like somehow add `CONVERT` to resulting SQL query? I can resort to using pure SQL code, but it will make my project prone to SQL injectons.

Comment: Which backend are you using? Might be worth experimenting. [Natively support uniqueidentifier column type #79](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/79) mentions some of the difficulties involved and mentions [Add native support for Python UUID data type #177](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/177) and [microsoft/mssql-django](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django) along the way. mssql-django did have native support of uuid+uniqueidentifier at one point, but my reading of the code suggests that has been subsequently removed.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, if by backend you mean `'ENGINE'` property of `settings.DATABASES`, I use `mssql`. Do you mean that by opting for another engine I may be able to use this type of field?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to create a CharField then make it unique so that you can use it as unique identifier - `sample_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False,null=False,unique=True)`